# Extract location, rotation, scale data from 2D Stabilization node for a given frame (using Python or UI)?

Tags: python, transforms, tracking

I'm using a *Stabilize 2D* node as the last node in my *Compositing* workflow and would like to know the location, rotation and scale that it's applying at a particular frame, e.g. frame 201.

I want this data because I plan to render things out and then split the sequence at this frame and insert a short sequence in-between and want to know the applied location etc. so I can apply it (with a *Transform* node) to the in-between sequence such that things line up. The separately created in-between sequence would line up already if it weren't for the changes introduced to the footage on either side by stabilization.

In the end, I'll join things up such that I have the first half of my stabilized sequence, then have an already stable in-between sequence (that's the product of 3D rendering rather than video footage), and then the last half of my stabilized sequence.

Conceptually, I'm locking down the stabilization for the in-between sequence and then resuming it afterward. To do this, I plan to render out the different parts separately, apply a transform to my in-between sequence to get it to line up with the sequences on either side and then joining things up in the *Video Editing* workspace. If you can think of a better or different approach please tell me.

Using the nodes shown below and selecting the *Stabilize 2D* node, I've got as far as accessing this node in the Python console like so:

```
[x for x in C.scene.node_tree.nodes if x.select][0]
```

But it's got a large number of attributes and I haven't worked out how to essentially ask it "give me the values you'll apply at frame 201 such that I can create a *Transform* node that applies the same effect".

[image: compositing nodes]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't access this data from python... maybe you could add a keyframe in movieclip editor datasheet with 'I' then with 'Clear Track Path' button delete all other keyframes ahead, and use that as source for stabilization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I found I could recover the translation, rotation and scale (applied by the stabilization) by comparing the original and stabilized images outside Blender using the OpenCV function [`estimateAffinePartial2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d).

I've described the process in more detail [here](https://github.com/george-hawkins/image-align).